# What others can do with my android keystore signing?

Tags: android, google-play, android-keystore

I have a android source and hired a freelancer to edit it and update the code for me. But the thing is she signed and built the APK for me and it is now currently uploaded in Google Play Store. I just got the information that I can't update the app now since she got the app keystores (certificate).

Will I be able to update the app even if I get the keystores to her? Is it not advisable to do that or I should just republish the app?

Comment: just ask her to give you that keystore file, with details like alias name, keystore password. so if you want to upload new version for your app sign your new apk with the same keystore, and upload it to playstore

Comment: is it also possible to change the information on the certificate like name, organization, etc.?

Comment: you can change alias name and password, but i think we can not change organisation name etc.

Answer (score 1):

When you upload an application to Google Play it should always be signed. If you update the application with a new apk, it should be signed with the same signature. Without the keystore you will not be able to publish updates for it. You can only create a new application with a new Keystore (and delete the other one).

It's important that, if you're the owner of the application, keep the keystore that is used to sign it in Google Play.

Comment: How do you keep it in Google Play??

Comment: ask the freelancer to give the keystore and it's passwords to you

Comment: I am not the OP, I am just curious as to how do you `keep the keystore in Google Play` ??

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that I should have the keystores. But my problem is updating the app because i don't have the keystores.

Comment: I've edited my answer, was a little poorly written. What I meant is that he needs to keep the same keystore he uses to upload the app to Google Play (because he needs to sign always the apks with the same signature)

Comment: If you don't have it, and you can't recover it, I think your only option here is to delete that application, create a new one, and use a keystore that you can control to sign the aplication

Comment: So it is not advisable for me to ask for the keystores?

Comment: For sure, you should ask for them. It is your app, you should control it and be the owner of the signature